# Save screen shot in IOS Simulator different to recommended size of launch image

Tags: xcode, image, ipad, ios-simulator, app-launcher

I am using the 'save screen shot' feature of the IOS Simlator to create my launch images for the IPad. However, it is providing me with an image size of 768x1024 in portrait mode, but the recommended size is 768x1004. I get the same anomaly with the other modes. Using my image, I get a warning, but it works perfectly. If I cut the status bar off the image, it is 768x1004, but gets stretched behind the real status bar when running. If I select 'hide status bar during application launch' in Xcode, the status bar vanishes permanently and does not reappear at all.
What should I be doing? Will the app store reject my app if the launch image is the wrong size - as I said, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

For what is worth, I have always used 768x1024 Default images and never got a rejection (for that).